# Unpack operation not allowed in this context Pylance

Tags: python

I have a function like this:

```
def post(self, request):
    submitted_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    content = ''
    apples_royal_gala = 'Appels Royal Gala 13kg 60/65 Generica PL Klasse I'
    ananas_crownless = 'Ananas Crownless 14kg 10 Sweet CR Klasse I'
    peen_waspeen = 'Peen Waspeen 14x1lkg 200-400 Generica BE Klasse I'

    if submitted_form.is_valid():
        uploadfile = UploadFile(image=request.FILES["upload_file"])

        name_of_file = str(request.FILES['upload_file'])
        uploadfile.save()
        print('path of the file is:::', uploadfile.image.name)          

        with open(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
                               f"{uploadfile.image}"), 'r') as f:

            print("Now its type is ", type(name_of_file))
            print(uploadfile.image.path)

            # reading PDF file
            if name_of_file.endswith('.pdf'):
                pdfFile = wi(filename=uploadfile.image.path,
                             resolution=300)
                text_factuur_verdi = []

                image = pdfFile.convert('jpeg')
                imageBlobs = []

                for img in image.sequence:
                    imgPage = wi(image=img)
                    imageBlobs.append(imgPage.make_blob('jpeg'))

                for imgBlob in imageBlobs:
                    image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(imgBlob))
                    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang='eng')
                    text_factuur_verdi.append(text)

                    totalString = re.findall(ExtractingTextFromFile.make_pattern(
                        apples_royal_gala), (*text_factuur_verdi[0])) + re.findall(ExtractingTextFromFile.make_pattern(
                            ananas_crownless), (*text_factuur_verdi[0]))

                    content = totalString
            # ENDING Reading pdf file

            else:
                content = f.read()
                print(content)

        return render(request, "main/create_profile.html", {
            'form': ProfileForm(),
            "content": content
        })

    return render(request, "main/create_profile.html", {
        "form": submitted_form,
    })
```

and the output is this:

```
['3.304,08', '3.962,00']
```

But I want to have the values without brackets('[]').

So I try to  unpack the values from the list with the '*'.

But then I get this error:

```
Unpack operation not allowed in this context  Pylance
```

So my question is: how to tackle this?

Comment: Which context? Please make a [mre].

Comment: Where do you try to unpack anything?

Comment: It is really unclear to me what you are expecting unpacking to do there. You have a `list` object that contains `str` objects. You *don't want a list*, is what I gather when you say "But I want to have the values without the brackets" *but you don't explain what type of object you are trying to create*. It is important to understand, `list` objects *don't have brackets*, that is merely how they are represented when you ask for a string representation... are you trying to create *a string*?

Comment: Yes, I am pretty sure OP means string, as in, he wants all of the values of a list, spaced in a string, therefore, without the brackets, as lists would have when printed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`join` is what you're looking for:

```py
...
output = ['3.304,08', '3.962,00']
unpacked = ", ".join(output)
print(unpacked)
> '3.304,08, 3.962,00'
```

If you want `"'3.304,08', '3.962,00'"` as the output, you will need to do

```py
unpacked = ", ".join(["'"+e+"'" for e in output])
```

Comment: Thank you. But what means the e?

Comment: It is called `list comprehension` in Python, which is basically a for loop over a list in a single line. `e` is the list element that's been iterated over `output`. See [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) for reference.